# CSS Grid Columns limit card width based on background image

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a dynamic CSS grid layout of a bunch of cards right now which scales to fit the width of the screen

[image: 5x card layout]

However, when there are only a couple of cards, the cards stretch out to fill the whole screen because of the `1fr` property, and I would like to limit them only as wide as their background image is or scale the image to the size of the card, or something along those lines.

[image: x2 stretched cards]

Here is the code for the CSS grid

```css
.resources-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

I was able to achieve somewhat the desired result by doing

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, auto));
```

but it still stretched past the limit.

Here is the code for the card (condensed)

```html
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="votes-container"></div>
      <div class="comments-container"></div>
    </div>
    <img class="card-image" :src="content.image" />
    <div class="card-contents">
      <h1 class="title">{{ content.title }}</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">{{ content.subtitle }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
.card {
  min-width: 15rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;

  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;

  flex: 0 0 auto;

  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  text-align: left;

  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    background-position-x: center;
  }

  .card-contents {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;

    width: 2rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to scale the background image by adding a `width: 100%` tag on top of the existing `height: 100%` tag, which prevents the ugly background scaling shown in the original images.

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position-x: center;
}
```

[image: Better looking 2x stretched images]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, something like this will work (see modified repeat option on grid-template-columns):

```css
.wrapper { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.card { 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the issue is I need the number of columns to be responsive to adapt to how many cards are shown and not just locked at 3. The cards have a minimum width of 15rem, so when the website is viewed on a narrower window they overlap. I think I need to be able to define a min width (15rem) and then a responsive max width based on the width of the background, and then also make it responsive like when using 1fr in the minmax function.

Comment: Would flex-wrap not be a better option for you then instead?

Comment: I was originally working with flexbox instead of CSS grid, but I was unable to create a solution where all of the cards had an equal width. Just figured out that I could get the image to scale by adding a `width: 100%` on top of the `height: 100%`, thanks for your help. It got me in the right direction in the end :)